# How many spells would a 3rd level Sorcerer have with a Charisma 19?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, spells, sorcerer

I'm trying to create a character with an [online character sheet from google docs](https://docs.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AjfaolOnvs6gdEZNenNDdVBTSDBPME04S1JranRSSEE&mode=public) and the calculations are coming up unexpectedly. I suspect there is an error in the formula, so I want to make sure I understand the character creation rules.

For a 3rd level Sorcerer with a CHA of 19 they will know: 6 - 0 Level Spells; 3 1st Level Spells (7 per day); 1 - 2nd Level Spell (4 per day)? This is what the semi-auto calcing sheet came up with.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the *Pathfinder Core Rule Book*:

On page 17 (Table 1-3: Ability Modifiers and Bonus Spells) a Charisma of 19 would give a +4 modifier to CHA and 1 extra bonus spell for 1st-Level spells.

In addition to this, on page 72 (Table 3-14: Sorcerer) a 3rd level Sorcerer only can cast 5 1st-level spells per day. Your Charisma score bonus spells would be added on here, allowing you to cast your selected 1st-level spells 6 times per day.

And finally, on page 73 (Table 3-15: Sorcerer Spells Known), a 3rd level Sorcerer would only know 5 0-level spells and 3 1st-level spells.

**So, to answer your question, your 3rd level Sorcerer would have the following:**

*0-Level Spells*: 5 known, Unlimited times per day

*1st-Level Spells*: 3 known, 6 times per day

**This is without your Bloodline bonus spell at 3rd level. Including that you would have the following:**

*0-Level Spells*: 5 known, Unlimited times per day

*1st-Level Spells*: 4 known, 6 times per day

Comment: That's what I thought. So the Google Docs character sheet is calculating too high. Probably what a Wizard would get instead of a Sorcerer. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it's overpowering your L3 Sorcerer quite a bit (for example, you don't get access to level 2 spells until you are 4th level!) Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Check for the new version: 11-14-2011 Version 1.5.4
Fixed a bug with the sorcerer spell calculations.